# AdMob interstital can't work correctly with plugin "Firebase-Admob-Unity"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial

- I'm using Unity (ver 5.3.4).
- I want to use Admob Interstital on iOS & Android.
- I choosed this plugin: https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity

**issue**
It seems this plugin has three methods of interstitial ad.

1. `loadInterstitial()`
2. `isInterstitialReady()`
3. `showInterstitial()`

I expect it works correctly like this code.

```
void Start{
    // Prepare AD
    loadInterstitial();
}

void ShowAd(){
    // Prepare check
    if(isInterstitialReady()){
        // Display AD
        showInterstitial();
    }
}
```

But it seems `loadInterstitial()` not only load ad but also display ad.
So I want to know how to load ad without display.

Thank you very much.